# Does Voice of Authority work with harmful spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric

Voice of Authority from Order Domain cleric states that

> If you cast a spell with a spell slot of 1st level or higher and **target** an ally with the spell, that ally can use their reaction immediately after the spell to make one weapon attack against a creature of your choice that you can see.

**Since being in a range of *fireball* makes you a target, can you activate Voice of Authority by casting *fireball* on your ally?**

Note: I use fireball just as an example and comedic effect. I'm pretty sure it's not the intended use of Voice of Authority, but I'm curious of the RAW reading of using harmful spell to activate the feature.

Answer (score -1):

Since the description of Voice of Authority doesn't exclude harmful spells, its prerequisite is met if you target your ally with a harmful spell.

Comment: Is that ruling on target backed by official rules? The spell description for fireball does use the word "target" to refer to creatures who will be affected by the spell.

Comment: This is what I get for trying to apply common sense without looking at the PHB. I could do with a bit more precise language when describing how fantasy magic works. I feel that my interpretation is reasonable but there's clearly room to say otherwise and it's not central to the answer, so, sidetrack rescinded.